# iOS Swift 2.0 - AvAudioPlayer is not playing any sound

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

Lately I have run into an issue while using the beta version of Xcode (7.0).
I am not able to hear the sound that I play through this code:
(It is a ViewController from the Main.storyboard, there is a button connected to `buttonTouchUpInside()`)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("NO AUDIO PLAYER")
    }

    return audioPlayer!
}

@IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {
    let backMusic = setupAudioPlayerWithFile("sound", type: "wav")
    backMusic.play()
}

}
```

Comment: Does your code crash ? The reason that you dont hear is because AVPlayer is not retained, you create it and call it play but it does not remain around. Just create a property for backMusic and it should work fine.

Comment: The code does not crash. I'll try that out, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to move the declaration of backMusic out of your IBAction:

Try like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var backMusic: AVAudioPlayer!
    // ...
    @IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {
        backMusic = setupAudioPlayerWithFile("sound", type: "wav")
        backMusic.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make Leo's solution even clearer, you can't declare AVAudioPlayer to be a local variable, or it will be disposed when exiting that scope, before it can play anything.

Comment: saved my day. Thanks a lot.